# When I Try To import ftpserver from pyftpdlib, it outputs "ImportError: cannot import name ftpserver"

Tags: python, importerror, ftp-server, pyftpdlib

```
from pyftpdlib import ftpserver

HOSTNAME = "localhost"
PORT = 5555

authorizer = ftpserver.DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("papakri", "dancinghotdogs", "/Users/alexandrospapakribopoulos/Documents/Programming")
authorizer.anonymous("/Users/alexandrospapakribopoulos/Documents/Programming")
handler = ftpserver.FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer

connection = (HOSTNAME, PORT)
ftpd = ftpsserver.FTPServer(connection, handler)

ftpd.serve_forever()
```

I am trying to create a basic FTP and connect with and connect it with an HTTP server that I have created.
I am a bit new to python so even if it is something really obvious please point it out.
I am using python 2.7.10.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed pyftplib package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly did you `pip install pyftpdlib` already if not do that first
- Next step you import the ftp server incorrectly `from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer` this is how you should import it according to the doc https://pythonhosted.org/pyftpdlib/tutorial.html#building-a-base-ftp-server
- You can then feed the connection detail into the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package is installed:

```
pip install pyftpdlib
```

Make sure you did that with your virtual environment installed if you use one. Forget this sentence if you don't know what I'm talking about.

Then, according to the example from the repo, 
your code should be :

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("user", "12345", "/home/giampaolo", perm="elradfmw")
authorizer.add_anonymous("/home/nobody")

handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer

server = FTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 21), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Your snippet might be out of date vs your package version.

Comment: This helped me fix it. Thanks A Lot.

Comment: that'd be nice to tell the world your problem has been solved marking the answer as correct ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have osx operation system.for mac you can install python use `brew` like this:

```
brew install python
```

and then you have `pip` package manager for Python, then you can install `pyftpdlib` package with this command:

```
pip install pyftpdlib
```

and then you can try again to run your code

in summary I can say you can isntall packages in operation systems like this:

**linuxbased with apt-get repository manager** :

```
sudo apt-get install pip
pip install your_package_name
```

**osx** :

```
brew install python
pip install your_package_name
```

**CentOS/RHEL**

```
sudo yum install python-pip
pip install your_package_name
```